# how to attach a pdf generated with dompdf to a drupal mail

Tags: email, drupal-7, dompdf

I have generated a pdf using DOMPDF in the usual way:

```
$html = "<html><body></body></html>";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
```

but instead of download it, I want to attach to a mail and send it to a recipient.

Im using the api for mailing that Drupal 7 provides, but when I try this:

```
$message['params']['attachments'][] = array(
                  'filecontent' => $dompdf,
                  'filename' => 'filename',
                  'filemime' => 'application/pdf',
                );
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMPDF as array in /var/www/html/sitename/sites/all/modules/smtp/smtp.mail.inc on line 449
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $dompdf variable is an instance of the dompdf class. To get the content of the rendered PDF use `$dompdf->output()`.

```
$message['params']['attachments'][] = array(
  'filecontent' => $dompdf->output(),
  'filename' => 'filename',
  'filemime' => 'application/pdf'
);
```